# cordova-plugin-file-transfer upload appearing as GET request even though httpMethod set

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, upload, file-transfer

I am trying to upload an image taken by the camera in my app. I am using the cordova-plugin-file-transfer for my app and I am trying to send the image data to my server to store (PHP).

I have set these options:

```
const options: FileUploadOptions = {
    fileKey: 'file',
    fileName: imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
    headers: {},
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    chunkedMode: false,
    params: { action : 'INSERT', lineid : this.lineId },
};

this.fileTransfer.upload(imageData, encodeURI(url.replace('https', 'http') + 'pages/attachments.php'), options).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

However, my server seems to receive this request as a GET method rather than a POST therefore it's not going through the correct upload process on my server side.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin forces the upload function to use either `'PUT'` or `'POST'`

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/dc8fbd78a234bd88450ebe01835c60371bc2cf8e/www/FileTransfer.js#L127-L131

This looks like you have an issue with your server side code. Check the endpoints you are hitting and debug from there.